# Number showing as NaN in <input> when set with jQuery .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the value of an input field with jQuery `val()`

```
$('[name="paytype1"]').change(function(){
    var total = big_total();
    total = parseFloat(total);
    total = total.toFixed(2);
    console.log(total);
    if(isNaN(total)) {
        alert(total);   
    }
    $('[name="pay1amt"]').val(total);
})
```

And all that is being shown in the browser is `NaN`.

Running `console.log(total)` shows a number, e.g. 61.00, and no alert is being triggered.

The `big_total()` function is returning the number correctly (it calculates from numbers in other input fields).

```
function big_total() {
    var big_total = 0;
    $('.total').each(function(i){
        big_total = big_total + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    big_total = big_total.toFixed(2)    
    return big_total;
}
```

The inputs with the class total are being added to the page dynamically by jQuery after an ajax call.  This is the html that is inserted:

```
<div class="grid_12 alpha omega line-items">
    <div class="grid_1">CH02<input type="hidden" name="item_code[]" value="CH02">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="1458">
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3">
        DVA Regular consult
        <input type="hidden" name="item_desc[]" value="Subsequent consultation">
        <input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="Service">
    </div>
    <div class="grid_1">
        <input type="text" size="3" name="qty[]" value="1" class="qty" max-length="3">
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2">
        <input type="text" size="7" name="sub_total[]" value="61.00" class="sub-total">
    </div>
    <div class="grid_1">
        <select name="tax[]">
            <option value="$taxitems[ID]">0%</option>
            <option value="$taxitems[ID]">10%</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2">
        <input type="text" size="7" name="total[]" value="61.00" class="total" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="grid_1 omega">
        <div class="remove_stock_line"><img src="images/collapse.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the drop down triggering the function:

```
<div class="grid_8 alpha omega">
    <div class="grid_3 alpha">
        <select name="paytype1" class="pay_type">
            <option default="" value="nill"></option>
            <option value="cash">cash</option>
            <option value="HICAPs">HICAPs</option>
            <option value="EFTPOS">EFTPOS</option>
            <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
            <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
            <option value="American Express">American Express</option>
            <option value="Other card">Other card</option>
            <option value="EFT">EFT</option>
            <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>  
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 omega">
        <input type="text" size="10" name="pay1amt" value="" onclick="select();" class="pay_values">
    </div>              
</div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: [I suspect you're getting `NaN` out of the `big_total()` function](https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/b5nvdtow/), but since we can't see it there's no way to know.

Comment: Is the value returned from `big_total()` also NaN?

Comment: if the big_total() isnt a function then thats the problem

Comment: the console.log() of total return a number and that is what is coming out of big_total().  Wouldn't isNaN(total) be triggering an alert if it was NaN?

Comment: You could avoid some slow responses, and get some more input, if you just add the `big_total()` function here... it can't be that big, right?

Comment: most likely the returned value from big_total will itself be NaN. Please paste your big_total or a fiddle would be better

Comment: big_total() posted.  Just copped some flack about posting too much code in the past so I probably tend to be overly cautious.  This function is also being used on other functions that update similar fields and they work fine.

Answer (score 1):

this is working

```
function big_total() {
    var bg_total = 0;
    $('.total').each(function(i){
        bg_total = bg_total + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    big_total = bg_total.toFixed(2)    
    return bg_total;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[name='paytype1']").change(function(){
        var total = big_total();
        total = parseFloat(total);
        total = total.toFixed(2);
        console.log(total);
        if(isNaN(total)) {
            alert(total);   
        }
        $('input[name="pay1amt"]').val(total);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

in your `big_total()` function, `$('.total')` element is only a class of an input which occurrence is one. why are you using `$.each` for it

```
$('.total').each(function(i){
    big_total = big_total + parseFloat($(this).val());
});
//you can just replace the use of .each above to this in the big_total function, except you have special reason for that
bg_total = bg_total + parseFloat(".total").val());
<input type="text" size="7" name="total[]" value="61.00" class="total" readonly="">
```

When you said in the question `And all that is being shown in the browser is NaN. Running console.log(total) shows a number, e.g. 61.00, and no alert is being triggered.`

1. NaN will only be shown to when the value of the input with class `.total` starts with non-numeric. that is only when you should expect the `if(isNaN(total)) {alert(total);}` to work.
2. yes the `console.log(total)` is showing the value 61.00 because The big_total() function is returning the number correctly, but this is what i dont know if you have taken care of `(it calculates from numbers in other input fields)`

Apart from these your problem should be solved.

Comment: Thanks but [name='paytype1'] is a drop down list with the payment type in it, .e.g cash, card etc.  Tried editing $('[name="pay1amt"]') to $('input[name="pay1amt"]') and made no difference.

Comment: edit your post and add your html code

Comment: yeah but i cant see any dropdown list with name "paytype1"

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this function. But since we cannot see your full source code and you haven't shared your `big_total` function we can only speculate. From my personal experience I see only two possible scenarios.

1. `big_total()` returns a non-numeric value or has leading non-numeric character like `$4339`, because `parseFloat()` ignores trailing non-numeric characters except period(.) eg: `83483a;lsdfad` will not give you an error. But since you don't see any error in the console or an alert, this scenario can be ruled out.
2. The only other explanation is that, some other part of the code is overwriting the value set by this function.

If I were you I would follow these steps to debug.
I would replace:
  `var total = big_total()`
 
with: 
 `var total = 1234.56;`

If you see the result in `$('[name="pay1amt"]')` then the problem is in `big_total`. If you still see NaN then I would look elsewhere in the code to see where the value is getting overwritten.

*This is not related to the question but is very important.*
Do not use the variable name `big_total` inside the function `big_total()`. Javascript does not differentiate between functions and variables when storing and retrieving them from the stack. Parenthesis directs the interpreter to execute the function while the absence of parenthesis directs the interpreter to reference it as a variable (without executing it).

```
//Try this code
function hi(){
    //without parenthesis it is treated as a variable
    alert('without ()\n\n'+hi);
            return 6;
}
//with parenthesis it is executed as a function
alert('With () \n'+ hi());
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about using the function name as a variable name within the function.